# Property type is not a type of overriden

Tags: kotlin

Sorry for not specific title, I don't really know how to name it better.
I have the following example:

```
class User

interface Repository<T, ID>

interface UserRepository : Repository<User, Long>

abstract class RepositoryTest<T, ID> {

    abstract var repository: Repository<T, ID>

}

class UserRepositoryTest : RepositoryTest<User, Long>() {

    //Error: Var-property type is "UserRepository", which is not a type of overriden 
    lateinit override var repository: UserRepository

}
```

I need this architecture for the database testing. `Repository` have methods like insert, save, delete etc. I want to use this abstraction in `RepositoryTest` to delete all entries and insert needed data before each test. In `UserRepositoryTest` I want to specify the repository as `UserRepository` (it's a child of `Repository`), but I take an error mentioned in the example.
Why it gives me the error? I thought I can pass a subtype`s type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`repository` is a `var` field. Since `UserRepositoryTest` can be referred as `RepositoryTest<User, Long>`, you should be able to assign `Repository<User, Long>` to the `repository` field. However, it does not have to be a `UserRepository`, hence the error.

Changing `repository`to `val` in `RepositoryTest` class should fix it.